# How can the elements of a PHP array with matching characteristics be processed into a series of aggregates?

Tags: php, arrays

Essentially I want to perform a kind of grouping against a PHP array, and then squash the elements in each group into a single aggregate value.

Specifically, I have a PHP array with the following form:

```
[
    [date, int],
    [date, int],
    [date, int],
    ...
    [date, int]
]
```

and I want to process this so that I end up with an array of arrays each containing a unique date and the sum of the ints that went with that date in the original array, e.g.:

```
[
    ['2017-01-01', 1],
    ['2017-01-01', 1],
    ['2018-01-01', 1],
    ['2019-01-01', 1],
    ['2019-01-01', -1],
    ['2020-01-01', -1],
    ['2020-01-01', 1],
    ['2020-01-01', -1]
]
```

should result in this:

```
[
    ['2017-01-01', 2],
    ['2018-01-01', 1],
    ['2019-01-01', 0],
    ['2020-01-01', -1]
]
```

The original array is in date order.

What's an efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: That is invalid PHP notation. Are those dates strings? Then they should be quoted.

Comment: That is indeed invalid PHP notation, I was sure you'd be able to get the idea.  I'll quote them, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this (assuming your array of arrays above is called `$source`):

```
$destination = array();
foreach ( $source as $date_value ) {
    if ( isset( $destination[ $date_value[0] )) {
        $destination[ $date_value[0] ] += $date_value[1];
    } else {
        $destination[ $date_value[0] ] = $date_value[1];
    }
}
```

This will create an array with the dates as keys and the sums as the values of those keys.  Not specifically what you were asking for.  To format it otherwise:

```
$new_destination = array();
foreach ( $destination as $key => value ) {
    $new_destination[] = array( $key, $value );
}
```

Now `$new_destination` should be an array that matches your desired output.  This can be done when creating the first array, but will get very messy.  So even though it creates two loops, it prevents the need for nested loops, and is likely more efficient than doing it in one block.

Note that I haven't tested this, so it may contain syntax errors or need to be modified slightly to get what you need, but it should put you on the right track.

Comment: Oops.. edited and fixed. The `if` was intended to prevent a PHP Notice by assigning versus adding.. bad copy and paste on my part, but it should be all good now.

Comment: Wouldn't this result in `[ '2017-01-01' => 2, '2018-01-01' => 1, ...]` where they OP was looking for `[ ['2017-01-01', 2], ['2018-01-01', 1], ...]`

Comment: @Sean You're right. I've added some additional bits to reformat it.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this, assuming your input is in `$arr`:

```
foreach ($arr as list($date, $num)) {
    $result[$date] = isset($result[$date]) ? $result[$date]+$num : $num;
}
```

Now `$result` will be almost as you asked for. It will in fact produce key/value pairs, where the key is the date, and the value the number. If you really prefer the nested array format, then:

```
foreach ($arr as list($date, $num)) {
    if (!isset($result[$date])) $result[$date] = [$date, 0]; 
    $result[$date][1] += $num;
}
```

This will still have the dates as keys, but they will have the pairs as values.
If you want a sequential array instead of dates as keys, then add:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in `[ '2017-01-01' => 2, '2018-01-01' => 1, ...]` where they OP was looking for `[ ['2017-01-01', 2], ['2018-01-01', 1], ...]`